# ajax and php reload for paging having trouble figuring it out

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

```
$(function(){
$('.page').click(function() {
    var paging = $(this).attr("name");
    var dataString = 'page='+paging;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo $backtrack; ?>shop.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(){
            $('#products').load('shop.php/skateboards/ #products > *', function(){
                $('#products').delay(200).fadeOut();
                $('#products').delay(600).fadeIn();
            });
            $(".current-page").attr("class", "");
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

});

I am guessing this is not working because I am reloading the part of the page that gets the post. What I want to do is post the page number to the current page and then reload the items inside the products div, with it being the next set of items

Comment: Why do you put this: " #products > *" in your URL string that is used by the load function?

Comment: @NickStemerdink so it does not laod <div id="products"><div id="products"> (double div)

Comment: That will not work because this parameter is for the URL only, you cannot put a selector in there. Reference: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to do something like this:

```
$('.page').click(function() {
    $('#products').delay(200).fadeOut();

    var paging = $(this).attr("name");
    var dataString = 'page='+paging;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo $backtrack; ?>shop.php",
        data: dataString,
        complete: function() {
            $.get('shop.php/skateboards/', function(data) {
                 $('#products').replaceWith(data);
            });
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```